# How do I download a local version of a component or page file to my PC?

Tags: 2011

Working in SDL Tridion 2011. I need to download files I have in Tridion to my HDD. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You'll need to be a little more specific. What files are you talking about? Are they Multimedia Components in Tridion? Normal Components? Pages? etc.

Comment: Normal components and pages sorry.

Comment: It is unusual to need to save copies of Pages and Components. Can you tell us **why** you need to this, as it may lead to a better solution than downloading them using WebDav?

Answer (score 3):

You are a bit vague when it comes to downloading files, what files do you expect to download? A Page is not a file, nor is a Component, but for that you can use the WebDAV interface to access the item as a file.

See the [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A94DA13A-C3E2-4B76-B3B3-78E4547B0930) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) can tell you more about the [WebDAV client](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A94DA13A-C3E2-4B76-B3B3-78E4547B0930) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) and how to set it up and use it.

On the Components source tab (also available for Page- and Component Templates) you can also find a <kbd>Save to Disk</kbd> button, through that you can also save the source to disk of that item.

[image: Save to Disk]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Is there anyway to setup WebDAV if I can't login to that page? Should that be a different password than the one that allows me on tridion?

Comment: what page are you referring to that you can't login?

Comment: The WebDAV client link. I do not have login.

Comment: @user3010823 Then read the instructions supplied in the link next to it (http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion), or see the **WebDAV Connector** topic in the User Manual of your CMS (under Help & Community in the Dashboard)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Webdav connector in order to accomplish it. You will need to map the webdav url as a new Drive then you can browse the CMS as a Windows Directory set and copy the files you need.

There are some restrictions and it will allow just some kind of item types, like components and multimedia.

You can find some details here [Mapping a Webdav as a Network drive](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=webdav%2520map%2520drive&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1389712384876&currentQuery=webdav%2520map%2520drive&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_5C45FF81C2474FF1BC57C371E967B617&query=webdav%2520map%2520drive&scope=&filename=WebDav_Adding.xml&docid=task_5C45FF81C2474FF1BC57C371E967B617&inner_id=&tid=8b4c4c55-ac35-4daf-93f9-ad17b7903e3b&addHistory=true&resource=) - login is required.

Comment: Is there anyway to setup WebDAV if I can't login to that page? Should that be a different password than the one that allows me on tridion? Thanks!

Comment: It is the same, if you are using Windows Server you should install the Windows Feature "Desktop Experience" in order to avoid that issue